# Deploy to remote glassfish from Netbeans fails

Tags: netbeans, amazon-ec2, glassfish, web-deployment, remote-server

Trying to deploy to remote glassfish 4.1 (same as on my local machine) from Netbeans fails without any error message (that I could find).

When I do "Run project" from Netbeans 8.0.2, I get a `remotetest (run)` in the status bar (remotetest is the name of my project, which is just a "Hello from Servlets" default JSF project). When I click on the `1 more` spot, it says it's deploying my .war to my remote server. After 20 minutes and 1 second, I get

> Deployment error: Deployment timeout has exceeded. See the server log
>   for details."

(the first time I waited that long... actually right now, it's been "deploying" about 60 minutes and hasn't stopped).

There is nothing in the remote glassfish server log after glassfish server has finished startup, no sign of the deployment trial. This directly after rebooting my AWS EC2 instance.(I read somewhere that the micro instances might not be good for a full blown server, normally it seems that it's taking between 0 and 12% in top. What I do see, right now though, is the java process taking 75% cpu and 40% memory when the "deployment" has been going on for an hour or so, and it remained so after stopping the deployment from Netbeans end.)

What I ***can*** do after a dozen hours of setting things up and googling:

- Deploy my app to local glassfish.
- Connect to my remote glassfish admin page via port 4848
- move the .war to remote .../autodeploy, see it deploy and have it visible remotely at myhost:8080/remotetest
- connect to remote mysql via Netbeans (not sure if relevant)
- ssh a basic java "hello world" from Netbeans to remote machine (not sure if relevant)

What I've tried:

- opened up various ports for custom TCP rule from the EC2 management console , including 8080,8181,4848
- tinkered with every possible switch from Netbeans and glassfish I could think of
- Google my butt off
- sleep over it
- rinse and repeat

The glassfish server logs show two warnings after startup:

> All SSL cipher suites disabled for network-listener(s). Using SSL
>   implementation specific defaults

and three SEVERE:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>       org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.generatedASM.DomainResource not found by org.glassfish.main.admin.rest-service [97] at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at ...

I can't make anything of those. Nothing in the log since I started the deployment a couple of minutes after the server was up and visible in Netbeans.

Comment: Have you tried using GlassFish 4.0? There is a known remote deployment bug in 4.1 where deploying a war to a remote server just fails. I think this is fixed in [the latest Payara release](http://payara.co/downloads), so that might be good to try if you're keen on using GlassFish 4.1 (which Payara forked from)

Comment: Thanks, after installing 4.0 both on my PC and remote (didn't even need to start on PC, just install so Netbeans could add a remote 4.0) things started working. This is fine for me now, as I'm just trying to learn this stuff and not worried about old versions security issues or such.